# RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CUDA but got backend CPU for argument: ret = torch.addmm(torch.jit._unwrap_optional(bias), input, weight.t())

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, tensor

When the `forward` function of my neural network (after the training phase is completed) is being executed, I'm experiencing `RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CUDA but got backend CPU for argument #4 'mat1'.` The error trace indicates the error happens due to the call of `output = self.layer1(x)` command. I have tried to move all the data of the tensors to my GPU. It seems I miss something to be moved as well.

**Here is the code I have tried:**

```
use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if use_cuda else 'cpu')

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size).cuda(device)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size).cuda(device)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU().cuda(device)

    def forward(self, x):
        x.cuda(device)
        output = self.layer1(x)  # throws the error
        output = self.relu(output)
        output = self.layer2(output)
        return output


def main():
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ])

    mnist_trainset = datasets.MNIST(root='D:\\MNIST', train=True, download=False, transform=transform)
    mnist_testset = datasets.MNIST(root='D:\\MNIST', train=False, download=False, transform=transform)

    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=mnist_trainset, batch_size=100, shuffle=True)
    test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=mnist_testset, batch_size=100, shuffle=False)

    input_size = 784
    hidden_size = 500
    output_size = 10
    num_epochs = 5

    learning_rate = 0.001

    model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
    model.cuda(device)

    lossFunction = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    lossFunction.cuda(device)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    losses_in_epochs = []
    total_step = len(train_loader)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            images = images.reshape(-1, 28 * 28)

            out = model(images)
            loss = lossFunction(out, labels)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            if (i + 1) % 100 == 0:
                print('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, i + 1, total_step,
                                                                         loss.item()))

            if (i % 600) == 0:
                losses_in_epochs.append(loss.item())

    with torch.no_grad():
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        for images, labels in test_loader:
            images = images.reshape(-1, 28 * 28)
            out = model(images)
            _, predicted = torch.max(out.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: {} %'.format(100 * correct / total))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**The software stack:**

```
Python 3.7.1
torch 1.0.1 (with Cuda 9.0)
Windows 10 64-bit
```

Comment: Try using `to` instead of `cuda` for all instances.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, could you share any clear advantage(s) of this preference? @blue-phoenox

Comment: `cuda` let's you only switch between GPU's, while `to` lets you switch between any `device` including cpu. Main point is: I would just not mix them in one program, as `to` is more versatile I would go with `to` over `cuda`.

Comment: Makes sense, of course, the good practice is using uniform programming concepts as much as possible. @blue-phoenox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error only happens only at the testing step, when you try calculating the accuracy, this might already give you a hint. The training loop runs without a problem.

The error is simply that you don't send the images and labels to the GPU at this step. This is your corrected evaluation loop:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for images, labels in test_loader:
        images = images.to(device)  # missing line from original code
        labels = labels.to(device)  # missing line from original code
        images = images.reshape(-1, 28 * 28)
        out = model(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(out.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
```

BTW you don't need to send all your layers to the GPU separately (at your class `__init__()`). It's better to just send the whole instantiated model to the gpu at once.

Comment: I actually run the code after this change without any problems. I think blue-phoenox's (now deleted) answer is not solving the issue, but his points are correct nevertheless.