# Error Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gpu, huggingface-transformers

I have the following code taken directly from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-abstractive-text-summarization-with-pretrained-t5-text-to-text-transfer-transformer-10f6d602c426) with some pretty little modifications:

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
import json 
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Config
from torch import cuda

df = pd.read_pickle('df_final.pkl')

model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-base')
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-base')
device = 'cuda' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

text = ''.join(df[(df['col1'] == 'type') & (df['col2'] == 2)].col3.to_list())

preprocess_text = text.strip().replace("\n","")
t5_prepared_Text = "summarize: "+preprocess_text
#print ("original text preprocessed: \n", preprocess_text)

tokenized_text = tokenizer.encode(t5_prepared_Text, return_tensors="pt", max_length = 500000).to(device)


# summmarize 
summary_ids = model.generate(tokenized_text,
                                    num_beams=4,
                                    no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
                                    min_length=30,
                                    max_length=100,
                                    early_stopping=True)

output = tokenizer.decode(summary_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

print ("\n\nSummarized text: \n",output)
```

When executing the `model_generate()` part i get an error like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e8e9819a85dc> in <module>
     12                                     min_length=30,
     13                                     max_length=100,
---> 14                                     early_stopping=True).to(device)
     15 
     16 output = tokenizer.decode(summary_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py in decorate_no_grad(*args, **kwargs)
     47         def decorate_no_grad(*args, **kwargs):
     48             with self:
---> 49                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     50         return decorate_no_grad
     51 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\generation_utils.py in generate(self, input_ids, max_length, min_length, do_sample, early_stopping, num_beams, temperature, top_k, top_p, repetition_penalty, bad_words_ids, bos_token_id, pad_token_id, eos_token_id, length_penalty, no_repeat_ngram_size, num_return_sequences, attention_mask, decoder_start_token_id, use_cache, **model_specific_kwargs)
    383             encoder = self.get_encoder()
    384 
--> 385             encoder_outputs: tuple = encoder(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    386 
    387         # Expand input ids if num_beams > 1 or num_return_sequences > 1

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    539             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    540         else:
--> 541             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    542         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    543             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_t5.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, inputs_embeds, head_mask, past_key_value_states, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    701         if inputs_embeds is None:
    702             assert self.embed_tokens is not None, "You have to intialize the model with valid token embeddings"
--> 703             inputs_embeds = self.embed_tokens(input_ids)
    704 
    705         batch_size, seq_length = input_shape

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    539             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    540         else:
--> 541             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    542         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    543             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\sparse.py in forward(self, input)
    112         return F.embedding(
    113             input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
--> 114             self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1482         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1483         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1484     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1485 
   1486 

RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _th_index_select
​
```

I've searched this error and fouund some other threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278566/runtimeerror-expected-object-of-backend-cuda-but-got-backend-cpu-for-argument) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799486/expected-object-of-device-type-cuda-but-got-device-type-cpu-in-pytorch) one but they didn't help me much since their case seems to be completely different. In my case there are no custom instances or classes created, so i don't know how to fix this or where the error come from.

Could you please tell me where is the error coming from and how could i fix it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly moving your model to the GPU.

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-base').to(device)
```